# Cant use localStorage in nextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, local-storage, redux-thunk

I'm developing a cart system and the problem is that, when I add a product to the cart, it works in context and localStorage; but, when I refresh, the data is gone.

```js
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const {
  cartItems
} = useSelector((state) => state.cart)
const [cartState, setCartState] = useState({
  cartItems: [],
})
const initialRender = useRef(true);
useEffect(() => {
  if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartState"))) {
    const storedCartItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartState"));
    setCartState([...cartItems, ...storedCartItems]);
  }
}, []);
useEffect(() => {
  if (initialRender.current) {
    initialRender.current = false;
    return;
  }
  window.localStorage.setItem("cartState", JSON.stringify(cartState));
}, [cartState]);
```

Comment: Did you check in the chrome devtools?
Why the `window` before `localStorage` in the second useEffect?

Comment: @GabrielPichot Why not? It is a method of the window so it should not make any difference

Answer (score 0):

You are earsing the value of the local storage on the first render

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (initialRender.current) {
    initialRender.current = false;
    return;
  }
  //here
  window.localStorage.setItem("cartState", JSON.stringify(cartState));
}, [cartState]);
```

You should :

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (initialRender.current) {
    initialRender.current = false;
  } else {
    window.localStorage.setItem("cartState", JSON.stringify(cartState));
  }
}, [cartState]);
```

Comment: it dont work bro :(((

Comment: Can you try again with the edit please ?

Comment: it said TypeError: destroy is not a function :'(

Comment: @Yun There is no such thing in the code you provided, no idea where it comes from

Comment: I think the cause is async and await, bro

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is have some state to check against to see if the client side is loaded:

```
const [clientLoaded, setClientLoaded] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  setClientLoaded(true);
}, []);
```

Then anywhere you can check if clientLoaded is true, for example in another useEffect hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  clientLoaded && doWhatever; // do whatever you want here 
}, [clientLoaded]);
```

Or in you render method:

```
{clientLoaded && <span>Render this if the client is loaded</span>}
```